# calculate the 3-integral

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals

$\int\int\int\limits_{  V} z \, \mathrm{d}x \, \mathrm{d}y\, \mathrm{d}z $   $V=(x,y,z)\in R^{3}: \frac{x^{2}}{a^{2}} +\frac{y^{2}}{b^{2}} + \frac{z^{2}}{c^{2}} \le1, z\ge0  $

I have to calculate the integral.
I think that spherical coordinates could be a good idea such as:

$r'=r \sin a$

$x=r \sin a \cos b$

$y=r r \sin a \sin b$

$z= r \cos a$

But I have no idea what is next, how looks like limits of the integrals etc... Any help will be great for me!

Answer (score 1):

Try using 
$$
x = a\rho \mathrm{sin} (\phi) \mathrm{cos} (\theta),\\
y = b\rho \mathrm{sin} (\phi) \mathrm{sin} (\theta),\\
z = c\rho \mathrm{cos} (\phi).
$$
The compute the jacobian to do the co-ordinate transform for the integral i.e. $(x,y,z)\rightarrow (\rho,\theta,\phi)$ or explicitly
$$
\mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y\mathrm{dz} = \frac{\partial(x,y,z)}{\partial(\rho,\theta,\phi)}\mathrm{d}\rho\mathrm{d}\theta\mathrm{d}\phi 
$$
where the jacobian is given by
$$
\left| \begin{array}{ccc}
\frac{\partial x}{\partial \rho}  & \frac{\partial x}{\partial \phi}  & \frac{\partial x}{\partial \theta}  \\
\frac{\partial y}{\partial \rho}  & \frac{\partial y}{\partial \phi}  & \frac{\partial y}{\partial \theta}  \\
\frac{\partial z}{\partial \rho}  & \frac{\partial z}{\partial \phi}  & \frac{\partial z}{\partial \theta}  \end{array} \right|
$$
the limits

$$
\phi = [0,\pi/2],\\
\theta = [0,2\pi],\\
\rho = [0,1]
$$
since we are looking at the top half of the plane.

Comment: Ok but what about jacobian? How it will be look like? Should I multiply it by z?

Comment: I edited to give the Jacobian which you should be able to compute.

Comment: Thank you:) But should I multiply jacobian by the function? I'm not sure where to use it

Comment: Yes you mutiple the transformed z by the jacobian and integrate with the limits provided. Hope it helps.